# Printing Receipt From Parallel Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing

My program is a shopping cart program that takes in a UPC (Item ID), quantity/weight, and calculates the final price. The program has to print out a receipt of all the items purchased.

List of products:

```
UPC Description             PST   PPT     CIL
4011 BANANAS                1     0.49    123.2
4383 MINNEOLAS              1     0.79    187.3
3144 TANGERINES             1     1.19    135.5
4028 STRAWBERRIES_PINT      0     0.99    104
4252 STRAWBERRIES_HALF_CASE 0     3.99    53
4249 STRAWBERRIES_FULL_CASE 0     7.49    67
```

UPC is item code
PST determines whether the item is sold as units or in weight
PPT is price per unit/weight
CIL is the inventory (irrelevant for this question)

These values are stored in parallel arrays.

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/*
Description: This program will simulate a checkout at a grocery store. User will input
a UPC (item id) and a wieght/unit. The program will use parallel arrays to store these
values and output a final price at the end.
*/

int main(){
    int upc[6] = { 4011, 4383, 3144, 4028, 4252, 4249 };
    char desc[6][25] = { 
        "BANANAS               ",
        "MINNEOLAS             ",
        "TANGERINES            ",
        "STRAWBERRIES_PINT     ",
        "STRAWBERRIES_HALF_CASE",
        "STRAWBERRIES_FULL_CASE" };
    int upcR[6] = {};//storage array for reciept
    float pptR[6] = {};//storage array for reciept
    char descR[6][25] = {};//storage array for reciept
    int pst[6] = { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
    float ppt[6] = { 0.49, 0.79, 1.19, 0.99, 3.99, 7.49 };
    float stock[6] = { 123.2, 187.3, 135.5, 104, 53, 67 };//AKA CIL or Current Inventory Level

    float quant[6] = {};
    float price[6] = {};

    int option;
    do
    {
        printf("Welcome! Enter 1 to begin or 0 to exit.\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &option);
        if (option == 1){
            float subtotal = 0;
            float total = 0;
            float quantity;
            float discount1 = 0;
            float discount2 = 0;
            float tax = 0;
            int input;
            int element = -1; //element/row number
            do
            {
                printf("Enter UPC item code or enter 0 to start a new purchase.\n");
                scanf_s("%d", &input);
                if (input == 0)
                    break;
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)//Searches for element in parallel array using UPC
                {
                    if (upc[i] == input)
                    {
                        element = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (element == -1){ // checks to see if UPC is valid
                    printf("Invalid UPC. Please try again.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                if (pst[element] == 1)// checks if product is sold by units or weight
                {
                    printf("Weight: ");
                    scanf_s("%f", &quantity);
                    quant[element] = quantity;//stores elements for reciept array
                    price[element] = quantity*ppt[element];//stores elements for reciept array
                    if (quantity > stock[element]){
                        printf("This item is not available in this quantity.\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Units: ");
                    scanf_s("%f", &quantity);
                    if (quantity > stock[element]){
                        printf("This item is not available in this quantity.\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                subtotal += quantity * ppt[element];
                stock[element] -= quantity;

                quant[element] = 10;//stores elements for reciept array
                price[element] = quantity*ppt[element];//stores elements for reciept array
                upcR[element] = upc[element];
                pptR[element] = ppt[element];
                descR[element][25] = desc[element][25];
            } while (input != 0);
            if (subtotal > 50)  //5% discount for purchases over $50
            {
                discount1 = subtotal - (subtotal * 0.95);
            }
            int random = rand() % 10 + 1;
            if (random == 1){//random 5% discount if random number generated is 1.
                discount2 = subtotal - (subtotal * 0.95);
            }
            float discount = discount1 + discount2;//total 10% from >50 spent and/or random coupon
            tax = subtotal*.0825;//tax
            total = subtotal + tax - discount;
            printf("\n\nUPC\tDescription\t\tPPT\tWeight/Units\tPrice\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                printf("%d \t", upcR[i]);
                printf("%s \t", descR[i]);
                printf("\t\t%.2f \t", ppt[i]);
                printf("%.2f \t\t", quant[i]);
                printf("%.2f \t\n", price[i]);
            }
            printf("\t\t\t\t\tSubtotal\t$%.2f\n", subtotal);
            printf("\t\t\t\t\tDiscount\t$%.2f\n", discount);
            printf("\t\t\t\t\tTax\t\t$%.2f\n", tax);
            printf("\t\t\t\t\tTotal\t\t$%.2f\n", total);
        }
        else if (option == 0){
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("You have entered an invalid option.\n");
    }
while (option != 0);
    printf("\n\nUPC\tDescription\t\tPST\tPPT\tCIL\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    printf("%d \t", upc[i]);
    printf("%s \t", desc[i]);
    printf("%d \t", pst[i]);
    printf("%.2f \t", ppt[i]);
    printf("%.2f \t\n", stock[i]);
    }
        system("Pause");
        return 0;

}
```

So I enter in UPC and quantity over and over again until I'm done checking out. The problem is I need to somehow store these transactions to an array so that I can print out a receipt after I am done checking out. Right now what I have is a separate array for the receipt for each column and I am setting each element I check out into this separate array and then printing it out. This doesn't seem to be working well because 1) I can't copy the char array into the double array and 2)The empty arrays are all 0 which I don't want.

Is there a better way to do this? If anything, I would like advice on how to copy the string from the char array to a certain element to another array and I'll deal with the 0s later.

Here is an example of the program:

```
Welcome! Enter 1 to begin or 0 to exit.
1
Enter UPC item code or enter 0 to start a new purchase.
4011
Weight: 12.1
Enter UPC item code or enter 0 to start a new purchase.
4028
Units: 4
Enter UPC item code or enter 0 to start a new purchase.
4383
Weight: 8.3
Enter UPC item code or enter 0 to start a new purchase.
0


UPC     Description             PPT     Weight/Units    Price
4011                            0.49    10.00           5.93
4383    M                       0.79    10.00           6.56
0       T                       1.19    0.00            0.00
4028                            0.99    10.00           3.96
0       S                       3.99    0.00            0.00
0                               7.49    0.00            0.00

                                        Subtotal        $16.45
                                        Discount        $0.00
                                        Tax             $1.36
                                        Total           $17.80

Welcome! Enter 1 to begin or 0 to exit.
0


UPC     Description             PST     PPT     CIL
4011    BANANAS                 1       0.49    111.10
4383    MINNEOLAS               1       0.79    179.00
3144    TANGERINES              1       1.19    135.50
4028    STRAWBERRIES_PINT       0       0.99    100.00
4252    STRAWBERRIES_HALF_CASE  0       3.99    53.00
4249    STRAWBERRIES_FULL_CASE  0       7.49    67.00
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Note: the final array isn't the receipt, it's just an end of day inventory. The array above it is the receipt that I need help making.

Comment: Firstly, it will build if you replace all your `{};` with `{0};`.  When I did that, it seemed to work without a hitch.  Is the receipt the section that lists Subtotal, Discount, etc, etc?

Comment: The reciept is the table right above the subtotal.

Comment: My output (below) seems to contain the receipt output, or did I misinterpret what you said....  Just initialize your arrays with `0` and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

When I replaced ***all*** occurrences of `{};` with `{0};`.  It ran right away.

***Example***:

```
float quant[6] = {};
```

***Should be***:

```
float quant[6] = {0};
```

Here is an example output I got (you tell me what its missing)

[image]

***EDITS*** to address comment:

Add the `if(upcR[] != 0)` branch in this area of your code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            if(upcR[i] != 0)//add this condition test
            {
                printf("%d \t", upcR[i]);
                printf("%s \t", descR[i]);
                printf("\t\t%.2f \t", ppt[i]);
                printf("%.2f \t\t", quant[i]);
                printf("%.2f \t\n", price[i]);
            }
        }
```

And, the way you are assigning descR[] is incorrect.  You cannot set one string array equal to another using `=`. 
Make the following change in your code:

```
           // descR[element][25] = desc[element][25];
            strcpy(descR[element], desc[element]);
```

With these changes, the output now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thats what I get also. The problem is the description column. It's supposed to show an actual string (similar to original inventory). The other problem is the entire row that starts with a 0 in the upc shouldn't show up.

Comment: @dsa22 - probably time to turn on your debugger and put a break point in the area of code where that happens.  One thought is to use an `if()` branch to test the value of UPC for each row, if it is 0, skip the line.  (don't print it)  See my edit above...